# gridpane javafx node column span how to use?

Tags: java, javafx, html-table, gridpane

hey i have a gridpane and for one of the nodes i want it to be able to take up the whole row.

but i cant seem to figure out how to use GridPane.setColumnSpan(node, column span);

heres my code

```
grid.getChildren().addAll(animalFields(animal));
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.addRow(2, status, neutered, chipped, vaccinated, reserved);
        grid.addRow(3, statusCb,new HBox(neuteredYes, neuteredNo), new HBox(chippedYes, chippedNo), new HBox(vaccinatedYes, vaccinatedNo), new HBox(reservedYes, reservedNo));
        grid.addRow(4, new Label("people interested"));
        grid.addRow(6, sponsorsTable(((Adoption) animal.getAdoption()).getInterested()));
        GridPane.setColumnSpan(sponsorsTable(((Adoption) animal.getAdoption()).getInterested()), 6);
        grid.addRow(7, hBox2);
```

this is how it looks now

[image: Current look]

this is what i want it to look like

[image]

id be grateful for any help. thanks

Comment: That looks more like you want it to span multiple columns...

Comment: yes sorry i have been at this a while. i meant span all columns in the row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `GridPane.REMAINING`:

```
GridPane.setColumnSpan(yourNode, GridPane.REMAINING);
```

Comment: And you should check your row indices. You added row6 twice.

Comment: thanks i forgot to change it in the post. your method doesnt work for me.

Comment: What does sponsorsTable() look like? Are you using the same instance of your tableView?

Comment: you were right. i wasnt using the same instance of the table. thank you. i was on the verge of crying i was so long at this